# Remove redundant DNS servers in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dns

Ubuntu 22.04

Original:

```
root@ubuntu:~# resolvectl
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (ens5)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 12.34.56.78
       DNS Servers: 12.34.56.78 12.34.56.79
```

What I did:

1. Add `nameservers` entry in `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` file

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens5:
      dhcp4: yes
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```

```
netplan apply
```

2. Add DNS servers in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` file

```
[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
FallbackDNS=8.8.4.4
```

```
systemctl restart systemd-resolved
systemctl enable systemd-resolved
```

After rebooting:

```
root@ubuntu:~# resolvectl
Global
           Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
    resolv.conf mode: stub
  Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
         DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
Fallback DNS Servers: 8.8.4.4

Link 2 (ens5)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
       DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1 12.34.56.78 12.34.56.79
```

How to remove `12.34.56.78` and `12.34.56.79` in DNS server list?

Comment: are the 12.34.56 servers being passed out by the DHCP server? you are enabling DHCP, but then specifying DNS  servers. you can use a `dhcp4-overrides` with a setting `use-dns: false` to ignore the dns servers being pushed down via dhcp if you want.

Comment: @Frank Thomas Thanks, it worked!